# read JSON data from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a JSON like this return from a php file

```
[
 {"value":

       {"longitude":"103.8439764",
        "latitude":"1.0345","date":"Tue 04 Jun, 2013",
        "time":"12:27"}},

 {"value":
       {"longitude":"104.8439764",
        "latitude":"1.235","date":"Mon 03 Jun, 2013",
        "time":"12:28"}},
 {"status":
        "his_loc"
 }
]
```

How can I achieve the data like data.status or else ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse the data into an object variable:

```
var data = JSON.parse( datastring );
```

After that, you can address certain properties directly (e.g. data.status).

Comment: I dont know but I got this error when I tried to use the JSON.parse Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an array, you should access it like

```
var data = JSON.parse(json_string);
var status = data[2].status
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest restructuring the response from the server if possible, since the response is not so well-formatted.

**Step 1**: Change the response as follows:

```
{
 "value1":

       {"longitude":"103.8439764",
        "latitude":"1.0345","date":"Tue 04 Jun, 2013",
        "time":"12:27"},

 "value2":
       {"longitude":"104.8439764",
        "latitude":"1.235","date":"Mon 03 Jun, 2013",
        "time":"12:28"},
 "status":
        "his_loc"

}
```

**Step 2**: Parse the response to a JSON object.

```
var json = JSON.parse(responseString);
```

And now you can access the status as follows:

```
var status = json.status;
```

That's it!

Comment: Thank you very much to all of the answers :D